# IntelliSense not working in Visual Studio Code for C# after .NET update

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-7.0

I've recently updated from .net6 to .net7.

After this my VSCode has stopped showing IntelliSense.

If I go back to .net6, then it works again.

Any help ?

Comment: I assume you're using [`ms-dotnettools.csharp`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp)? If so, what's the value of your `dotnet.server.useOmnisharp` setting? What happens if you toggle it? What version of the extension do you have installed? What version of VS Code do you have installed?